# Connecting TFS repository to Azure DevOps

Tags: maven, tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have TFS repository for my Java maven project. I want to access that project in Azure DevOps by creating new pipeline. 
In Azure DevOps we have 5 options, one of them says to Create new Pipeline via TFVC where it asks for Repository URL (Connection URL).I mentioned Connection URL but still project structure is not displayed in Azure DevOps.

I also tried adding a new service connection(Add azure repos/Team Foundation Service connection), but it is not verifying connection.

I gave Connection Name,Connection URL Username and Password. 
Error which I receive is - Failed to query service connection API.

In short ,my TFS project is not importing in Azure DevOps. Please suggest what am I doing wrong.

Comment: You need to provide more specificity. Are you saying that you have an on-prem instance of TFS, and you want to **migrate** a TFVC repo to Azure DevOps? If so, do you want the repository to continue to be TFVC, or should it be a Git repository? Please explain what your current state is and what your desired end state is.

Comment: Yes I have a on-premise instance of TFS want to migrate the TFVC repo to Azure Devops. Major issue I am facing is to establish a connection . I am not sure why authentication is not passing. I am using windows authentication only.

Answer (score 1):

Guess you were talking about **Azure DevOps Service**. Since Azure DevOps also have a server call Azure DevOps 2019 which actually is the latest version of TFS at present.

There maybe some misunderstanding. It's **not able to directly access any TFS on-premise repository from Azure DevOps Service**.

You need to migrate data from TFS to Azure DevOps Services by using the [data migration tool](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devops/migrate/).

> The data migration tool helps you bring your data from Azure DevOps
>   Server to Azure DevOps in the cloud. Keep the same work item numbers,
>   Team Foundation Version Control check-in numbers, Git commit IDs, and
>   much more after you land in Azure DevOps.

But it do have some limitations of this tool. For example it *only supports the two latest releases of Azure DevOps Server at a given time*. Currently the following versions of Azure DevOps Server are supported for import:

- Azure DevOps Server 2019.0.1
- Azure DevOps Server 2019 Update 1

If you just need the source code in TFS repository without keeping any history, work items. The simplest solution is creating a new repository in Azure DevOps and download your code to your local repo from TFS. Finally commit/check in your local repo to your Azure DevOps Service.

If you are using TFVC in your TFS server and want to use Git in Azure DevOps Service. Then use [git-tfs](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs) as a two-way bridge.

Comment: Data migration guide I checked..looks a very lengthy and complex process. I don't have expertise in this area.I wish we could have some simple real time process to follow. We are doing this change to make life easy but following this seems to be a task in itself.

Comment: @Samira Sorry for the later reply. Understood  your concern, but it's caused by TFS-on premise server and Azure DevOps Service are two independent system. Then you could **only copy and past your source code**, quite easy.  In this situation, we generally advise users keep their TFVC repository in old TFS server online but read-only to view history.

Comment: I have done a workaround with which full history of my code, migrated to azure DevOps service repository using command line. And yes, your solution to download in local and then push to azure DevOps service also worked.